# How can I prove $\phi$ is surjective?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

$□_2 =\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ ;   \ |x|\leqq 1, |y| \leqq 1 \}$ (square)

$D_2$ : unit closed disk

$\phi$ : $□_2 \to D_2$ is given by

$\phi (x,y)=0$ $\big($if $(x,y)=(0,0)$$\big)$,

$\phi (x,y)=\dfrac{\max\{ |x|, |y|\}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(x,y)$ $\big($otherwise$\big)$

According to this site https://blancosilva.wordpress.com/teaching/an-introduction-to-algebraic-topology/homeomorphisms/ , $\phi$ is  bijective. I want to prove that $\phi$ is surjective.

Let $(u,v)\in D_2$.

If $(u,v)=(0,0)$, $\phi (0,0)=(u,v).$

If $(u,v)=(u,0)(u\neq 0)$, $\phi(u,0)=(u,v)$.

If $(u,v)=(0,v)(v \neq 0)$, $\phi(0,v)=(u,v).$

I searched $(x,y)$ when $(u,v)\neq (0,0),$ but I couldn't find.

How should I set $(x,y)$ which satisfied $\phi(x,y)=(u,v)?$

Comment: What is the image of the line segment $y=kx$?

Comment: @Empy2 If $y=kx$, $\phi (x,y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}(x,y) \ (|k|\leqq 1), \phi(x,y)=\dfrac{|k|}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}(x,y) \ (|k|\geqq 1).$ However, does this become a hint ?

Comment: That is the same line, just shrunk to the circle, endpiints $\pm(1,k)/\sqrt{1+k^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $0\leqslant y$ and that $-y\leqslant x\leqslant y$. Then $(x,y)=\bigl(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)\bigr)$ for some $\theta\in\left[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi4\right]$ and some $r\in\left[0,\frac1{\cos\theta}\right]$. Now, if $(u,v)=\bigl(r'\cos(\theta),r'\sin(\theta)\bigr)$, then$$\phi(u,v)=r'\cos(\theta)\bigl(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)\bigr),$$and therefore if $r'=\frac r{\cos\theta}$, then you have $\phi(u,v)=(x,y)$.

Can you take it from here?